# Разработка онлайн тестера.

Tags: php, html, javascript

Хочу написать онлайн тестер, и прошу помочь в идеях реализации.

**Задача**: Сайт задает N вопросов по очереди. Важны правильность и скорость ответов. Причем время между задаваемыми вопросами должно быть минимальным (очередной вопрос показывается мгновенно после ответа предыдущего).

**Вопрос**: Как лучше загружать вопросы? и где их проверять?

1) через Ajax, и так же отправлять ответы (тогда наверняка необходимо хранить статус, время каждого ответа в базе?),

2) все сразу загрузить и в скрипте выводить в нужной последовательности вопросы.

Как лучше обезопасить процесс ответов?

Comment: ну вы же понимаете, что с данными на клиенте человек может делать все что угодно ?

Comment: хотя вот если ключ расшифровки отдельным пакетом присылать через websockets или sse, то можно очень быстрое приложение сделать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax берёт из базы вопросы, выводит в блок, сразу берём начальное значение time(), пользователь ответил? снова берём time() и отправляем на сервер, ответ проверяется и записывается в табличку правильно или нет +время. Далее следующий вопрос и так далее. Можно и без Ajax. Время например хранить в cookie, или в session, номер вопроса в GET